How can/do I find the "main root" for wild grape vine in my yard?
I recently moved into a home that had been vacant for a year.  The wild grape vine has taken over much of the landscaping and starting to climb the house.  I know little about plants and have read the previous question/answers and have learned a lot. BUT how do I find the main root to the grape vine? All I seem to find is of "off shoots."  I pull them out of the ground and the next day it seems to re-appear.  It's like playing whack-a-mole!  Thank you.

Are you sure its a grapevine and not Virginia Creeper? A photo of the foliage might be helpful...

Doesn't really sound like grape vine behavior, unless you are exaggerating considerably.
Anyway, you can dig down to excavate the root and follow it back, rather than just pulling off the shoots, or you can treat with a herbicide rather than just  pulling off the shoots.
You could also look for a much thicker vine coming out of the ground somewhere (probably NOT right by your house.) Some of mine are as thick as an arm and climbing 80 feet into tree-tops. Thing being, I cut one and it's not sprouting again the next day, though it will come back eventually.

Yeah, I was hesitant to provide an answer with the "Big bad G" - but I imagine Glyphosate [ie Roundup ] would kill the root system and may be the best way to go here.

Pretty sure there are better ones for this application. In any case it depends on what is available where the OP lives and what, if any, they are willing to use.
